# YAML Pipeline Template Parameter Syntax

Tags: azure-devops

There are two documents on the Microsoft docs site which seem to declare different syntax for YAML template parameters.

I have not been able to deduce where the first one below is used, while the 2nd one works fine. I wanted to know if the version declaring type is deprecated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops-2019#template-expressions

```
parameters:
- name: 'solution'
  default: '**/*.sln'
  type: string
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#template-references

```
parameters:
  name: ''
  testFile: ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scripts you shared, are actually the two syntax of the **different usage scenarios** of parameter.

Let's map them with classic UI. In `msbuild` task, there has one blank which required you input `.sln`/`.csproj` file path:

[image]

As normal, you do not need change this value manually if there's nothing special on path. Because it is injected automatically by system in the task.

This is exactly same thing the below `YAML` script do:

```
parameters:
- name: 'solution'
  default: '**/*.sln'
  type: string
```

When you configure this in `YAML template`, in most scenarios, you do not need configured the value in `YAML` again, except you want to change to another value.

That's also why we said the `solution` parameter is **optional** in [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops-2019#template-expressions):

[image]

---

Contrary to the above, parameters are **required** when using the following syntax:

```
parameters:
  name: ''
  testFile: ''
```

You must pass value from YAML at this time, or it will cause execution error. Because there's no any values injected for them from start to end.

---

> I wanted to know if the version declaring type is deprecated.

Do you mean the task version declaring?  If yes, NO, it does not be deprecated. And it is the required one that you must provided. Because different task version may has different task configuration and execution logic.

The one you saw in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#stage-templates), just be the **shortcut** format. See this [tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#script). Until now, we only support below shortcut keywords, and they do not need version specified by user. Because they will automatically pick the default version value that our backend system defined:

`Script` => `command-line task`

`bash`   => `shell script task`

`pwsh/powershell`  => `PowerShell task`

`publish` => `Publish Pipeline Artifact task`

`download` => `Download Pipeline Artifact task`

---

**Update on 3/9/2020:**

```
parameters:
- name: 'solution'
  default: '**/*.sln'
  type: string
```

Above script is the richer YAML syntax which is the new feature we deployed recently, and it haven't supported in **Azure devops server 2019** until now (*3/9/2020*).

For Azure devops server 2019, it only support the older syntax, where defaults are declared as a mapping **without type or value constraints**:

```
parameters:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
```

Comment: If I copy and past the first example full version it will not run. I get "/steps/msbuild.yml (Line: 4, Col: 1): A sequence was not expected"

Comment: @J.D.Cain. Just run again, and all work fine. Did you change anything there? Or maybe you could share me the screenshots on your YAML and template? This error message represent the syntax of parameter are incorrect.

Comment: Could this be due to a difference between Service and Server? I'm using on prem server 2019 version currently.

Comment: I did a test and the template-expressions example from the original post works on Services but on the local Server version I get the 'sequence was not expected' error. Server version shows as Version Dev17.M153.5

Comment: @J.D.Cain. I'm afraid it indeed has some unknown on on-prem server. But, we should point this in documents. Since I think I need get get contact with on-prem team to confirm this, will get back to you once any update:-)

Comment: @J.D.Cain.  Have got the reply from on-prem team. Sorry for we did the docuemnt issue here. Unfortunately, the first syntax that you faced issue in on-prem server does not support in Azure devops server 2019. For azure devops server 2019, it only support the old syntax. I have update this key points into answer. Will contact our doc team to make change on documents.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Did they happen to mention if the syntax will be in the next update? I was told 2019 server had a 3 month update schedule.